# R summarytools(dfSummary) alphabetical order

Tags: r, r-markdown

(I'm new here so hopefully I am asking this in the correct way).

I am using Rmarkdown to create a summary table, and am using dfSummary within the summarytools package. I have created the table using this code:

[image]

[image]

Here is a picture of my current R-markdown:

[image]

I would like the order of the results for character variables to be listed in order of descending frequency, not alphabetical. I have read many pages summarize the package but cannot find an answer. Any help would be great!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your problem instead of screenshots

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to provide a reproducible example to help others to answer your question. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) post. [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) package is also a good way to start.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to do that in *summarytools* directly. (You can open an issue on the GitHub project page for a feature request.) The ordering by frequency is done only when there are more distinct values than allowed by `max.distinct.values`.

The easiest way to proceed would be to recode your character variable with `forcats::fct_infreq`:

```
library(forcats)
df$var_f <- fct_infreq(df$var)
```

The order of factor levels will be preserved in the the results.